# Possible Upper Bound of Sum of Divisors

Tags: functions, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of all divisors of $n$ (including $1$ and $n$). Is this function, $$f(x)=(e^\gamma(n+1))\ln(\ln n)+\ln(e^\gamma n)$$ an upper bound of $\sigma(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$? If so, how large must $n$ be to be "sufficiently large"?

Comment: $(1+\frac{1}{n})n$ is a weird way to write $n+1$.

Comment: @Jakobian Huh, I guess you are right. In any case, It just makes it easier for me to see a relationship.

Comment: @Jakobian Ok, fixed it.

Comment: The upper bounds from $\sigma(n)$ follow directly from the upper bound for $\omega(n)$ which follows from upper bounds for $\pi(x)$. Thus you need to make those correspondences concrete and see what bound for $\pi(x)$ you are assuming.

Comment: @reuns How does this help me? And how would I do that? I verified this numerically (aka no concrete "proof" in the traditional sense)

Comment: @reuns No, I care about the proof, I just want to know if it's possible to prove it for my function?

Comment: See https://www.emis.de/journals/JTNB/2007-2/article03.pdf p.7. The proof is based on estimates similar to that in the PNT and Mertens theorem